# Python dynamic import with submodules

Tags: python

I want to dynamically import functions from a module that will mimic the `import` keyword so all modules in the dotted string will be imported.

For example, I want to use a function I can do

```
import module1.module2.module3
module1.module2.module3.func()
```

When I import `module1.module2.module3` dynamically it does not work

```
importlib.import_module("module1.module2.module3")
module1.module2.module3.func()
```

I'm getting `NameError: name 'module1' is not defined`

To make it work I need to break the dotted string and import all parts:

```
importlib.import_module("module1")
importlib.import_module("module1.module2")
importlib.import_module("module1.module2.module3")
module1.module2.module3.func()
```

Is there a way to get the `import_module` to import all modules in the string?
(I tried `__import__()` with the same result)

What I want to do is use `eval` to run the function (I know `eval` is not recommended but this is not the question)

```
globals_ = {}
globals_["module1"] = importlib.import_module("module1")
eval("module1.module2.module3.func()", globals_)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'module2'
```

Comment: What if you just do `importlib.import_module("module1") module1.module2.module3.func()` ?

Comment: I have updated the question, I'm trying to use `eval` to call the function

Comment: `globals` is not a dictionary, but a function that _returns_ a dictionary. If you put a couple of parentheses `()` behind every occurrence of `global` in your code, it should work. And for `func` to be actually called, you need to put a couple of parentheses behind that, too !

Comment: The issue is that not all modules are imported, I updated the question again

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind it to a variable

```
module1 = importlib.import_module("module1")
```

Have a look at the docs for the semantics:
[python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by importing all the modules in the path to a "globals" and pass it to the `eval`

```
import itertools
import importlib

globals_ = {}
modules = itertools.accumulate([module] for module in "module1.module2.module3")
for module in modules:
    globals_[module] = importlib.import_module(".".join(module))

eval("module1.module2.module3.func()", globals_)
```

not sure if it is possible without importing all modules manually.